# What happens if we include a feature that based on our knowledge has no relationship with response?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, overfitting

Suppose that we have a dataset with $4$ features $x^{(1)}$, $x^{(2)}$, $x^{(3)}$, $x^{(4)}$ and a response variable $y$.

Suppose that for the dataset

$$\left\{\left(y_i, x_i^{(1)}, x_i^{(2)}, x_i^{(3)}, x_i^{(4)}\right)\right\}_{i=1}^n$$

we construct a prediction function

$$f({\bf{x}}, {\bf{w}}) = \sum_{i=1, 3, 4} w_i\phi^{(i)}(x^{(i)})$$

where $\phi^{(i)}(x^{(i)})$ are basis functions and ${\bf{w}} = (w_1, w_3, w_4)^\top$ are parameters. Notice that we have not included the second feature cause we know a priori that it doesnt affect $y$.

What would happen if, by accident, we included the second feature? For instance, would the training error increase / decrease? Would the test error decrease/increase? But most importantly, would the model now overfit/underfit?

(with respect to the model including only $1$, $3$ and $4$).

Comment: "Does not affect $y$" does not imply "is useless for predicting $y.$"  Search our site for terms like "mediation" and "confounding" and "causal" (analysis) for examples.

Comment: @whuber thank you! Not sure if it changes anything, but the way it is phrased in the assignment is "$y$ does not change with $x^{(2)}$.

Comment: That's a little subtler because the meaning of "does not change with" is unclear: one can *never* control for all possible confounding variables.  Thus, "does not change with" is either a theoretical assumption--which might or might not hold--or is some kind of empirical statement, in which case we have to ask about the sense in which it is even possible to "change" $x^{(2)}$ in a given dataset.  And in either case, does "change with" mean *when controlling for the other variables* or *while allowing the other variables to change with $x^{(2)}$ also*?